# Processing refund in SagePay API

Tags: php, api, curl, opayo

I am trying to test refund processing , all parameters seems to be correct but i am getting this error

```
VPSProtocol=2.23 Status=ERROR StatusDetail=3046 : The VPSTxId field is missing. VPSTxId={8642C32C-8743-93A5-8C3C-3C5D24E2E845}
```

As per their documentation there is no field `VPSTxId` for refunds.

Following is the code that i have tried:

```
$url = 'https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/refund.vsp';
$params = array();
$params['VPSProtocol'] = '2.23';
$params['TxType'] = 'REFUND';
$params['Vendor'] = 'VENDORNAME';
$params['VendorTxCode'] = 'Txn-abc123';            //Sample value given by me
$params['Amount'] = '3.00';
$params['Currency'] = 'GBP';
$params['Description'] = 'Testing Refunds';
$params['RelatedVPSTxId'] = 'ADE97B30-93DB-96EA-1D5F-FE1D5BJY456E2A';     //VPSTxId of main transaction
$params['RelatedVendorTxCode'] = 'VENDOR-131210115229-184';         //VendorTxCode of main transaction
$params['RelatedSecurityKey'] = 'JQFXUICCKO';       //securitykey of main transaction
$params['RelatedTxAuthNo'] = '81068219';            //vpsauthcode of main transaction

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,urlencode(http_build_query($params)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $curlTimeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
```

What is that i am  missing? Any help.

Thanks

Comment: There might be something wrong with their test service. Your code looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Changed my code a bit and it worked :)

```
$url = 'https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/refund.vsp';
$params = array();
$params['VPSProtocol'] = urlencode('2.23');
$params['TxType'] = urlencode('REFUND');
$params['Vendor'] = urlencode('VENDORNAME');
$params['VendorTxCode'] = urlencode('Txn-abc123');            //Sample value given by me
$params['Amount'] = urlencode('3.00');
$params['Currency'] = urlencode('GBP');
$params['Description'] = urlencode('Testing Refunds');
$params['RelatedVPSTxId'] = urlencode('ADE97B30-93DB-96EA-1D5F-FE1D5BJY456E2A');     //VPSTxId of main transaction
$params['RelatedVendorTxCode'] = urlencode('VENDOR-131210115229-184');         //VendorTxCode of main transaction
$params['RelatedSecurityKey'] = urlencode('JQFXUICCKO');       //securitykey of main transaction
$params['RelatedTxAuthNo'] = urlencode('81068219');            //vpsa

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $curlTimeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump( $response );
```

Comment: Hai chirag, i need integrate inframe method of sagepay in my project...but am stuck with that...could you help me?

Comment: see above example of the inframe example.

Answer (score 0):

3046 error means: 
You would have received this system message if you have not provided us with the correct value within the VPSTxId field. The VPSTxId value uniquely identifies a transaction to the Sage Pay system and if this value has not been submitted in full or this has been sent incorrectly formatted, you will be provided with this error message when the Sage Pay system attempts to validate it.

Regarding example - all required information is being submitted.

Provide the actual VPSTxID for Refund and RelatedVPSTxId and Sage Pay can check the logs for you if within 72 hours.

Comment: Could you give me sample code for integrate inframe method?

Answer (score -2):

```
strConnectTo<>"SIMULATOR" then
                                                                Session("Redirected")=true
                                                                response.Clear()
                                                                'response.redirect(strNextURL)
                                                                response.write "<iframe src=" & strNextURL & " width=500 height=600 align=center></frame>"
                                                                response.End()
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                end if
```

Comment: not in anyway an answer - just a copy and paste from a console or script.